# Clustering by individual tissue population post integration of two datasets

Tags: scrnaseq

Sorry if this question has been asked. Post batch correction and integration of two datasets, where cells of multiple different tissue types are present, I want to run clustering on cells of corresponding tissue types between the two datasets. Should I simply subset the integrated object to get each tissue type, scale the data and run PCA and then run clustering on it?

Thanks so much for the clarifications.